# Handle IE window close event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I need to handle when Internet Explorer (6, 8 and 9) window is closed, in order to ask his confirmation on it. I tried the `unbeforeunload`, but, as you might know, it's triggered also when any link is clicked, o a form is submited. Some can say to use event mouse coordinates, but there are several ways to break such a validation (Alt+F4 for ex.). There's also a way to set some variable to true when clicking links and check if in the event, but that does not work neither, as I got lots of various links on my pages, and the event is triggered multiple times in some cases.
Also I tried to solve the problem using frames, like: make 2 frames, put my pages to one frame, and to the other (with zero size) put a page with `onbeforeunload` handler. That would work just fine, but we work with a set of environment js, that we can't prevent to download, and those scripts remove any frames on the page, putting the entire page in the main window - fail…
Can anybody, please, suggest anything else?

Comment: Generally reacting to a window being closed is something you should avoid in the first place, because - as you noticed - it's very unreliable. You should redesign your web page/application, so that it's not necessary. What do you need to do when the window is closed?

Comment: well, the point is - I don't want such checkings neither; but customers do. I feel they just want to avoid accasional window closure, in order not to 'loose unsaved data'. We'll try to say that it's not the better way, but until that time we're trying to fing a solution. thanx for your advice

Comment: Well, if it just to warn the user, it's probablly ok to use. Setting a variable when a link is clicked is the right approach. In what way is the event triggered multiple times?

Comment: well, I just click the link, a javascript is run. so the event is triggered once before the javascript, and once after.

Comment: That normally shouldn't happen. What does the JavaScript do?

Comment: shows `confirm`, clear some cookies, than `window.location` is used. Why not just a link?.. Well, the script was used by a button previosly... I'll see if anything will change if I don't use it

Comment: Does it prevent the default action (`return false`)?

Comment: no. Now I've found out that it happend because of `window.location = 'url'` which must have caused new unload process. I removed that, and now the page looks preety nice (with the help of variable setting)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use onbeforeunload (and it sounds right), you should have a flag that is set so that the event only bothers asking if there is a reason to stay on the page.

```
var hasChanges = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {

    if (hasChanges) {

        return "You have changes that will be lost if you continue leaving the page";

    };

};
```

Then you just have to set the variable to true (`hasChanges = true`) if there is a reason to stay on the page...so if nothing has changed, clicking your other links will not trigger the dialog.

Comment: ye, but if something has changed and I click some links that do not case leaving the page - i'll get that message again. I've got lots of them on the pages

Comment: @Egor, wait, what do you mean clicking links within the page causes this? do you mean postbacks?

Comment: thanks, everything is okay now. I had problems becase of multiple `onbeforeunload` triggering. That was becase of `window.location = ` usage